# Using readablity.js from a Windows Desktop App

Tags: javascript, webbrowser-control, readability, htmlcleaner

I need to obtain a stripped down version of a web page programmatically using readability.js and the webbrowser control.

http://arc90labs-readability.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/js/readability.js

Do I have to load the web page I want to strip into the webbrowser control and then inject the readability javascript function into the HEAD and somehow call it from there (using WebBrowser1.Document.parentWindow.execScript) or is there some easier way to go?

Just looking for a bump in the right direction.

Thanks!